# Use same dns server for all (future) connections

Tags: networking, dns

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify, that all connections (even future, like when using wifi at some other place (=different SSID)) will be using pre-defined DNS server

When I have some (concrete) connections, I could go to IPv4 settings, and specify DNS server there (however, in case of new connection I would have to do it (and not forget it))

This may be particularly useful for some safe/filtering dns (such as opendns's 208.67.222.123 & 208.67.220.123)

Answer (score 5):

The way I do this is to set `supersede domain-name-servers` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. I've tried variety of options, including `head` or `tail` files, under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` folder, but only `dhclient.conf` does the trick for me. I've done it in 13.04, 14.04, and 15.04 versions of Ubuntu – always works.

Basic idea is that when you connect to a wifi access point, you receive certain information from `dhcp` server. The `supersede` option tells Ubuntu to replace whatever `dhcp` server sends you, with your own. In this case we supersede dns server.  So no matter what wifi you connect to, your ubuntu will replace wifi-given dns with its own.

Bellow is the sample of my own `dhclient.conf` file, notice the line `supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;`:

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf                                                  
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

Now, if you'd like you can use `prepend` option to use *both* wifi-given and your own server. In case wifi-given server fails, your request will be routed to the prepended dns.

Comment: I've also written a script to do manually set DNS for all connections stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` , however it seems that it doesn't work in 15.04. Let me know if you want it, and I'll link the answer to another, similar question where i posted it here

Comment: Hi @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy, I've found your solution works well for IPv4 DNS servers, but I can't get it to work for IPv6. I added these lines to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to set both IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers: `supersede domain-name-servers 84.200.69.80, 84.200.70.40;`   `supersede dhcp6.name-servers 2001:1608:10:25::1c04:b12f, 2001:1608:10:25::9249:d69b;`  When I query the use of DNS servers afterwards(`nmcli dev show | grep DNS`), only the IPv4 DNS servers are affected. The system still seems to adopt a suggestion from upstream for IPv6. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @django , I don't have that much experience using IPv6 settings, so can't say how to fix this. According to a few bug reports on Debian bug tracker suggest this option didn't exist in dhclient prior to 4.0 , but I don't think that's the case here. I've also found your question , https://askubuntu.com/q/1151913/295286, hopefully it can be answered. I've already +1'ed it. If I find something, I'll post an answer, but so far I've nothing to suggest

Answer (score 0):

/etc/resolvconf is the package that handles this.  It dynamically builds your /etc/resolv.conf file based on all sorts of rules.

You could set your preferred dns server in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

All other dns servers would come after that for all interfaces.

There are plenty of more advanced ways to get resolvconf to suit your particular requirements, have a read of the docs or howto's.