# Use Same DNS Server (IPv6) for All Connections

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, ipv6, dhclient

I want to oblige a single computer to only use specific DNS servers, for all network connections, including new ones, and be sure that only these DNS servers will be used.

I've found a solution by @SergiyKolodyazhnyy ([182750](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182750/use-same-dns-server-for-all-future-connections)) that seems to work well for IPv4 DNS servers, but I haven't been able to modify it to work for IPv6. I added these lines to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf to set both IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers:
`supersede domain-name-servers 84.200.69.80, 84.200.70.40;`
`supersede dhcp6.name-servers 2001:1608:10:25::1c04:b12f, 2001:1608:10:25::9249:d69b;`
When I query the use of DNS servers afterwards(`nmcli dev show | grep DNS`), only the IPv4 DNS servers are affected. The system still seems to adopt a suggestion from upstream for IPv6. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This might be a bug.  I filed a [bug report](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp/-/issues/98)